# asp.net AJAX Modal Popup Extender - Cancel button doesn't work after postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

The panel which my modal popup extender "shows" has an update panel within it, to handle valiation.

However, after postback, the close button doesn't seem to work.  It just closes the panel butit leaves the modalBackground [greyed out].

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender 
                        ID="ActivateModalDefault" 
                        runat="server" 
                        TargetControlID="btnRegister"
                        PopupControlID="pnlShowModal"
                        CancelControlID="CancelLinkButtonDefaultPage" 
                        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"> 
            </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Any ideas on why this would be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, the CancelLinkButton was wired up in jQuery as well, thus causing the very very strange behavior

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like normal behavior if it's been implemented correctly. Do you have more to add to this snippet?

Comment: You are correct sir.  The issue was, the CancelLinkButton was wired up in jQuery as well, thus causing the very very strange behavior